# mysqlCount not working with join,Showing wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables"shopinfo" and "rating" and i am trying to count review with Join but showing me wrong result

Here is my first table "shopInfo"

```
id  shopOpen    shopname
1   2           abc
2   1           xyz
3   2           dnu 
4   2           rfy
```

Here is my table "rating"

```
id  shopId      rating      review
1   2           3           Lorem Ipsum     
2   2           4           Lorem Ipsum
3   4           5           Lorem Ipsum
4   2           1           Lorem Ipsum
```

And here is my code which showing me wrong result in review count (showing me 6 , should be 3),
Where i am wrong ?

```
SELECT si.shopOpen, COUNT(r.review) as reviewCount, AVG(r.rating) AS AvgRating
FROM shopInfo si
LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.shopId=si.id
WHERE si.shopId = '2'
```

Comment: Looks like you should be selecting from `rating` and joining on `shopInfo`, not the other way around.

Comment: @SheetalGupta . . . Your query is fine.  Your results would be explained if you have duplicate `id` values in `shopInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `group by`. when you use aggregated functions like `sum(), avg()` you have to group by non-aggregated column. In your case it is `si.shopOpen`

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=badd51c3efe959f9a720756e269b183c) provided by @VBoka

```
SELECT 
    si.shopOpen, 
    COUNT(r.review) as reviewCount, 
    AVG(r.rating) AS AvgRating
FROM shopInfo si
JOIN rating r ON r.shopId=si.id
WHERE si.shopId = '2'
group by
    si.shopOpen
```

Comment: If you want to include it in your answer...: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=badd51c3efe959f9a720756e269b183c Also it I would like to note that in the question table shopInfo(si) does not have column shopId  but table rating(r) does...

Comment: @SheetalGupta try now and I have added fiddle link which has provided by VBoka.

Comment: Hi @SheetalGupta what does this mean "still giving me wrong result" ? Have you see the link ?

Comment: The missing `group by` should not be an issue here because only one row is being selected from the first table (i.e. the filter appears to be on the primary key).